# Site stops appearing on Google News when updating Next.js

Tags: next.js, google-news

My website stopped appearing on Google News when I updated Next.js from 12.1.6 to Next.js 12.2.5.

I didn't make any changes to the site, just updated the Next.js and put it into production environment.

I have two URL's available to test.

NextJs 12.1.6: https://www.fogaonet.com/noticias-do-botafogo/allan-e-torcedor-do-botafogo-tem-acerto-encaminhado-e-tenta-liberacao-do-al-wahda/

NextJs 12.2.5: https://staging.fogaonet.com/noticias-do-botafogo/allan-e-torcedor-do-botafogo-tem-acerto-encaminhado-e-tenta-liberacao-do-al-wahda/

*PS: The URL staging.fogaonet.com has noindex in the robots metatag to prevent duplicated content.*

Does anyone have any idea what problem could be happening?

Comment: can you rollback to the previous version and then check ?let us now

Comment: yes, with the previous version it works. I gave two examples, the www with version 12.1.6 and the staging with version 12.2.5.